# How to set Elements staying in place on all Devices

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to create an App in Android Studio based on Java. I created a login Form and used RelativeLayout. That form contains 2 EditText, 1 Button and 2 TextView. On Designer View it looks perfectly matching but when I'm installing the App on my Device, none of the elements are on their regular position. For example on the Designer in Android Studio I can see both EditText but after Installing it to my Device, the Username EditText disappears. So my question is how could I manage that all elements are on correct position on all devices.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the layout code ?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Thank you but I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this template to use the login form. 
You can also use constraint layout.

[image]

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/base_padding"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/base_padding">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/etUserName"
                        android:hint="user name"
                        android:background="@drawable/et_bg_grey"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/base_padding"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/base_padding"
                        android:paddingTop="13dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/base_padding"
                        android:background="@drawable/et_bg_grey"
                        android:hint="password"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/base_padding"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/base_padding"
                        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                        android:paddingTop="13dp"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/llProgressbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_brand"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:indeterminate="true"
                                android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
                                android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                            android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_brand"
                            android:text="Login"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
                    </LinearLayout>



                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/btnForgotPassword"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="Forgot Password?"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/base_padding_small"/>



                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

          </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I figured it out. Instead of using ConstraintLayout, I used RelativeLayout but now it works fine!

Comment: Welcome, TheSpookyRookie,